# How access or insert Azure AD B2C client data in to DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-ad-msal

I have a UWP application that is connecting through Azure B2C. However that's all I don't see where I can access the client username and password so that I can associate them with records in my sql database. I have the token but the connection doesn't make since and all documentation only gets you to the point you can use azure b2c and register after that I can't find anything.

I have gone through just about all Azure B2c Documentation, youtube videos from 1st and 3rd party contributors

No code to provide this is a architecture question.

I just need the road map to associate data in a database or create new records in a database from a native application that uses Azure B2C.

Answer (score 0):

The token contains a "sub" claim that is a unique identifier for the user.
You should be able to use that to connect the user to records in your database.

Comment: Thanks but there appears to be an issue with UWP itself. UWP unlike Asp.net is missing a xml config file so claims are never passed or associated so I don't get a unique identifier. UWP is missing access to ida's found in asp.net web.config. Please correct me if I'm wrong not being able to connect with B2C is really holding me up.